# What measure of central tendency is better measure ? Mean or Median?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset which has temperatures of different cities (total cities = 20).

Dataset:

```
  Columns->  city1 city2 city3 .... city20
             23    34     45         56
             34    56     26         54
             12    23     33         64
             34    67     31         42
```

Now for each row I want to find the mean and want to check if 50% of data points in a particular row are less than mean or not. If there are datapoints which are less than mean then I make a separate column where I replace the entire row by mean otherwise by median.

In below code I am calculating mean and then I just use for loop to check if the 50% datapoints are less than mean or not. Is there any other smart way to do this ? My ultimate goal is to create a column and each cell in that column will have mean of all temperatures from that particular row if 50% datapoints are less than mean otherwise use median in the column cell.

Code:

```
mean1 = data.mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row we compare the sum of different from mean and median , pick the less one , inyour case , row 1 to 3 we chose median, row 4 we chose mean

```
df['New']=np.where(df.sub(df.mean(1).values).pow(2).sum(1)>df.sub(df.median(1).values).pow(2).sum(1),df.median(1),df.mean(1))
df
Out[1429]: 
   city1  city2  city3  city20   New
0     23     34     45      56  39.5
1     34     56     26      54  42.5
2     12     23     33      64  33.0
3     34     67     31      42  38.0
```

Comment: I am new to numpy if possible can you just add a short descripton as I could not understand exactly what is happening inside `np.where()`

Comment: I want to find the whether mean or median is better measure for particular row for measuring central tendency of a particular row.